# Laravel - request validation for two nullable fields requiring at least one of them to be not-null

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent

My model has two nullable fields, but at least one of them must be not-null.
How do I setup request validation for this ?

```
$request->validate([        
    'field_1' => ['nullable'],
    'field_2' => ['nullable'],
    ...
]);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only two filed comparisons then you can use  [required_without:foo,bar,...](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-without)

```
 $request->validate([
        'field_1' => 'required_without:field_2',
        'field_2' => 'required_without:field_1'
    ]);
```

if it has more than two fields then [required_without_all:foo,bar,...](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-without-all)

```
 $request->validate([
        'field_1' => 'required_without_all:field_2,field_3',
        'field_2' => 'required_without_all:field_1,field_3',
        'field_3' => 'required_without_all:field_1,field_2',
    ]);
```

As per Doc

**required_without:foo,bar,...**

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any
> of the other specified fields are empty or not present.

**required_without_all:foo,bar,...**

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when all
> of the other specified fields are empty or not present.

[Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation)